# Find latest entity among Core Data relationships?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, entity-relationship

Is there an `NSPredictate` format for get the latest element among entities of a To Many relationship?

---

By example:

Having a `User` entity, and a `Device` entity.

Every `User` have a To Many relationship called `devices`.

Every `device` have a `lastConnectedDate`.

Now I want to select the `latest` device for a particular `user`.

Is there a short `NSPredictate` format for this?

Comment: Do I need sorting? Probably, aw.

Comment: Use `predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@",user`, sort by `lastConnectedDate` set the `fetchLimit` to 1

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, no need for `NSPredictate` at all. Simply **sort the relationship array**, wrapped up into a `User` method called `latestDevice`.

```
-(Device*)latestDevice
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastConnectedDate" ascending:YES];
    Device *latestDevice = [[self.devices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]] firstObject];
    return latestDevice;
}
```

Comment: This is not a very good approach as the devices will be faulted one by one for evaluation. @MikePollard suggestion is much more efficient.